# How to modify a collection of variables?

Tags: python

I came to a situation where I need (after some computation) to do a cumulative sum a couple of numpy arrays, i.e., do

```py
a1 = a1.cumsum()
...
a4 = a4.cumsum()
```

While this works, I wanted to make it more 'elegant' and do something like:

```py
for a in [a1, a2, a3, a4]:
    a = a.cumsum()
```

This does not work and I am pretty sure I understand why - but is there a syntax that can make it work?

(I believe that this would work if the objects were mutable and I used some in-place modifier, i.e., if I could write just `a.some_inplace_modifier()` in the loop. But here I need to use a function that returns a new object - so I guess it does not even matter whether the objects in the list are mutable?)

Comment: so you have some numpy arrays a1,a2,... and you want the cumulative sum over all of them?
if they have the same size, you could concatenate them and use numpy.sum() i guess

Comment: Is there any reason why you have separate names ``a1``, ``a2``, ... instead of a single *list* ``a``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4 = [x.cumsum() for x in [a1, a2, a3, a4]]
```

Comment: This is a nice, simple, and 'pythonic' solution, I should have thought about it myself..

Answer (score 0):

In your current syntax, `a` is a *copy* of each element from the list.

Modifying the variable `a` will not result in the element in the list being modified.

You need to modify the list directly, for instance by looping on the indices:

```py
var yourList = [3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(yourList)):
   yourList[i] = yourList[i].comsum()
```

or using list comprehension to create a new list and replace the old one:

```py
yourList = [a.cumsum() for a in yourList]
```

Comment: This is not accurate. They are references to objects because *every* value in Python is a reference to an object. But `a` holds a copy of the reference, and it would need to hold a reference to the reference for the desired behaviour to occur.

Comment: Actually, the first solution does not work: if I put my `a1`, .. , `a4` into the list, instead of `[3, 4, 5]`, then modifying `yourList[i]` does _not_ change the original variables.

Comment: correct, that will modify the values in the list, not the values referred by those individual variables. The second solution also won't modify the original variables. however, you can _replace_ those variables by doing some matching as in Junitar's answer.